# WindowActivated and WindowGainedFocus

Tags: java, windows, windowlistener

I'm looking at a listener that extends [WindowAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) and I notice that they're doing the exact same thing in both methods.

What is the difference between a window being activated and it gaining focus?
Is it possible to do one without the other? In my testing I've never been able to call just one which means they're making the application half as fast.

```
private class listener extends WindowAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("windowGainedFocus");
        method1();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("windowActivated");
        method1();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Is it possible to do one without the other?"* - In theory, yes, but the answer would then depend on if the behavior is the same across all platforms

Comment: @MadProgrammer what do you mean? if it helps I'm only concerned about windows (xp and 8)

Comment: The reason that it "might" have been done this way is because on some platforms one or the other methods doesn't get called.  You need to answer the question about which state you're interested in and focus on that.  Seen as you can test that both methods are been called, I'd focus on making sure they are called when you expect them to be

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've tested a bit. selecting the application from any means (alt tab, task bar, directly clicking on it) will call both methods. If there's a dialog window  I can't get either method to be called. If there's a child frame opened from the application, activating that will not call either method, the main application fires both as previously. This application only works in windows. What I'm interested in is optimizing it because the application is running a tad slow and I think this may be contributing as it's doing the same thing twice, for no appparent reason

Comment: From what I can ascertain from the documents, the focus listener will tell you when the window become focused (has keyboard focus) directly or indirectly (some child component got focus), where as the window listener will tell you when the window become active, this could be because you clicked the title bar or restored the window or some such.  So it now comes down to which trigger is more important to you

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't see how they can be different, if a window is active then it must have focus and vice versa, how can it be possible to trigger one without the other, clicking in the title bar fires both methods.

Comment: On some systems there might be a difference, in your case, under Windows, there is not.  I've not tried playing around with something like `JWindow` or a unfocusable window ... Not all windows are [focusbale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isFocusableWindow()) ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's been 3 years but I came across this question when trying to figure out an identical question asked recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53839062/4417306), there we were able to figure out what the difference is, hence I'm voting to close this as duplicate since the other question now contains a real answer with value. (even though this one is older. It has 357 views which indicates people search for this sometimes)